# Laravel ajax form data not posting to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I finally got my AJAX function working and it correctly posted data to the controller. But it only worked when the data being sent was included in the form action- /UoE/buy-product/{{product_id}}. But I only want the form action to be /UoE/buy-product/, as otherwise I am essentially sending the data twice. Once here, and once in my ajax function.

Here is my view

```
<form class="buy-product-form" id="{{$product->id}}" action="{{url('/UoE/buy-product')}}" method="POST">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary">BUY NOW</button>
                                </form>
```

Here is my AJAX function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $('form.buy-product-form').on('submit', (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var product_id = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).closest("form").attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': product_id},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function () {
                        window.alert($(this).closest("form").attr('action'));
                    }
                });
            }));
        });
```

Here is the first line of my controller (everything else here works fine)

```
 public function buyProduct(Request $request){
        $product_id = $request->id;
```

And here is my routes.php file

```
Route::post('/{university_code}/buy-product', 'UserController@buyProduct');
```

Comment: Replace `{university_code}` with `UoE` in your route.

Comment: But that is how it had been working for ages before I put in ajax. And I need to keep it as {university_code} if we are to expand our website in the future.

Comment: But does it work if you replace it?

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: From your route it seems you are missing a parameter in your controller method. What error you are getting?? use network tab of developer console of your browser to check the error.

Comment: It doesn't display a particular error, how can you tell that I am missing a parameter

Comment: you are using `{university_code}` in your route which is a parameter and can be changed as one you are using `UoE`, you need to use this as parameter of your controller method.

Comment: buy when I put that as a parameter in my controller method, it says that it is unused during my method. Also I thought that {university_code} was part of the URL not a parameter to the controller method?

Comment: I tried your code and everything worked fine. The only way I was able to reproduce your issue ($request->id not having any value) was by making sure `$product->id` returned a `null` value. Can you look at your Network tab and see what value you are sending to the controller? Does it work if you hardcode any value in the form id? (for exemple `id="1"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, I changed the routes file and removed that when a button was clicked.